# Get templatetag position

Tags: django, django-templates

I need a unique identifier for every occurrence of a templatetag. Is it possible to get the actual filename, line number and column where the templatetag is used?

I thought about using a variable in the context to count the instances of my templatetag but this would result in numbers being assigned twice if i had the following situation:

```
{% mytemplatetag %}
{% if random %}
    Some Text {% mytemplatetag %}
{% else %}
    Some other Text
{% endif %}
{% mytemplatetag %}
```

If random is true the templatetags would get the numbers 1,2 and 3. If random is false only the first and last templatetag gets a number and therefore numbers get assigned differently.

I just need a unique id for all the instances of mytemplatetag in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template tag you got the parser. You can use it to get the source file and the current character in the template like this:

```
@register.tag
def mytemplatetag(parser, token):
    template_loader, position = parser.command_stack[0][-1]
    print template_loader.loadname, position
```